# Sql server Row to column pivot, known column names unknown row data values

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've seen some posts on row to column pivots that require knowing 1) the possible values in the row to pivot, or 2) the number of values to pivot is the same for each pivot group. Here is my situation. I have a table that describes real property:

```
PARCEL     LEGAL                ACREAGE
1001       PORTION NW1/4        0
1001       AND SW1/2 38-9       0
1001       ACC. TO PLAT #882    320.00
1002       PORTION 38-10        320.00
```

The list of entries that correspond to a single distinct value of Parcel could be from 1 to 5. The last entry always has the actual acreage for that property, so I don't need the 0's. I want it to become like this:

```
PARCEL     LEGAL01              LEGAL02           LEGAL03              LEGAL04         LEGAL05          ACRES
1001       PORTION NW1/4        AND SW1/2 38-9    ACC. TO PLAT #882    <NULL>           <NULL>          320
1002       PORTION 38-10        <null>             <null>               <null>         <null>            320
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_number`

```
select * 
from
(select parcel, legal, 
        SUM(acreage) over (partition by parcel) acres, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by parcel order by legal ) rn 
 from yourtable) src
pivot (max(legal) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) p
```